# Publish only certain git branches

Tags: git, github, branch, fork

I am developing an Index and we are using Git. Amont many reasons is to use the ticketing system...

I currently have a branch "pre-v1.0" with all pre 1.0 versions in folders. This is Public

I have another branch "1.0" with the released version, the official one. This is Public

I have another "current" onto which I fix the 1.0. This is Public

I want to have private "dev" branches where I can test ideas, but I need to share these with the other scientists, not with everyone.

Any idea?

The repo is under the Institute name.

I could fork into my account and share it with the other scientists... is that the only option? (I only have a personal free account in github) Will it also transer tickets and issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't push the non-public branches into a public repository. For the others, that should have access to your private branches I recommend to create a second bare repository, to that only you and the others have access to, for example within your local network. Another solution is, that they directly add your workcopy as remote repository.

Comment: +1. I think adding other scientists repos as remotes would be the best option here.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to Fork the public repository into a private repository into the same account?